# Proving logical equivalence - using soundness?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The problem is the following:

"Suppose that we have two formulas $\sigma, \psi$ such that $\models \sigma \rightarrow \psi$. Prove that this implies that $\sigma \wedge \psi$ is logically equivalent to $\sigma$."

My question is: is there a way to prove this statement without the use of truth tables? Like the title suggests, I was told that soundness is one potential approach. Whenever I see a logical equivalence, though, I intuitively feel like a truth table is the way to go.

Comment: Soundness only applies if you have an axiom system defined. If you wanted to you could define an axiom system and then show $\sigma \to \psi \vdash \sigma \wedge \psi \leftrightarrow \sigma$, though this would probably end up being fairly lengthy

Comment: Yes, this can get proven without truth tables.  Check the definition of logical equivalence again.  Does that help?

Comment: @aidangallagher4 Since this was part of an exercise-sheet in a basic course on propositional logic, I don't think we are supposed to define the system ourselves.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood My textbook simply states: "Two logical formulas $\sigma$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent if and only if $\sigma \Leftrightarrow \psi$ is a tautology." Currently, the only way I know of showing that something is a tautology is the use of truth tables - hence, my question.

Comment: I really meant 'choose' rather than 'define' to be honest (you can try and define one if you want though). See for example here: https://www.planetmath.org/axiomsystemforpropositionallogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods of showing that a well-formed formula is a tautology.

1. Truth tables.
2. Equational logic.  This requires writing equations and an exhaustive case by case analysis such that all valuations of the variables get shown to produce the designated value (usually '1') for the well-formed formula.  I prefer using Polish notation and will use it in the following example:
   We want to show that CCpCqrCCpqCpr = 1 for all valuations of 'p' and 'q'.

First we check when p = 0.  CC0CqrCC0qC0r.  Notice here that C0Cqr,
C0q, and C0r, all have the form Cxy.  C00 = 1,  and C01 = 1.  Thus,
for all x, C0x = 1.  Thus, CC0CqrCC0qC0r = C1C11.  Note that C11 =
1.  So, C1C11 = C11, and finally C11 = 1.  So, CC0CqrCC0qC0r = 1.

Now we check when p = 0.  CC1CqrCC1qC1r.  Note that C10 = 0, and C11 = 1.  Thus, C1x = x for all x.  So, CC1CqrCC1qC1r = CCqrCqr.  C00 = 1, and C11 = 1.  THus, Cxx = 1.  So, CCqrCqr = 1.  It follows that CC1CqrCC1qC1r = 1.

That covers all cases for valuations of the variables, and thus CCpCqrCCpqCpr = 1.

3. Use of an a sound formal system with pre-specified rules of an inference and/or axioms.  This would involve soundness, as first we should show the system sound in that all of the axioms are tautologies, and the rules of inference always preserve truth.  Consequently, any inferred well-formed formulas also will be tautologies.  Then we produce a formal proof of the desired well-formed formula.  For the example given we would need to show that Cxy implies EKxyx.  For more details of how to show this we would need to have a particular formal system at hand.